# How to show the chartjs bar chart data values labels as text?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, bar-chart, axis-labels, chart.js

I am creating a bar chart using chartjs.org and i am trying to show the values of the vertical axis labels as texts (ex: "under performance", "ok", "Good", "Excellent").

kindly check this wireframe for better understanding.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaK0n.png

Here is my code looks like.

```
<canvas id="barChart"  height="200"></canvas>

var barData = {
        labels: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "Late",
                fillColor: "rgba(3,169,244,0.5)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(3,169,244,0.8)",
                highlightFill: "rgba(3,169,244,0.75)",
                highlightStroke: "rgba(3,169,244,1)",
                data: [19, 25, 46, 77, 90, 95, 35],                 
            },
            {
                label: "My Second dataset",
                fillColor: "rgba(26,179,148,0.5)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(26,179,148,0.8)",
                highlightFill: "rgba(26,179,148,0.75)",
                highlightStroke: "rgba(26,179,148,1)",
                data: [25, 35, 55, 60, 60, 88, 15],                 
            }
        ]
    };

    var barOptions = {
        scaleBeginAtZero: true,
        scaleShowGridLines: true,
        scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
        scaleGridLineWidth: 1,
        barShowStroke: true,
        barStrokeWidth: 2,
        barValueSpacing: 5,
        barDatasetSpacing: 1,
        responsive: false,
    }

   var ctx2 = document.getElementById("barChart").getContext("2d");
   window.myPieB = new Chart(ctx2).Bar(barData, barOptions);
```

I would love to have some suggestions on this. Let me know if need anything from my side.

Answer (score 1):

ChartJS is a good, but simple charting library.

Rather than modifying the source code of ChartJS to display your custom legends, it's probably easier for you to create your bar chart in native html canvas using lines and rectangles.

William Malone does a good job describing barcharts here:

http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-canvas-javascript-bar-graph/

Whether you decide to customize ChartJS or "roll your own", here is code to draw text rotated vertically and centered at a specified X,Y:

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var x=50;
var y=50;
var width=75;
var height=200;

ctx.strokeRect(x,y,width,height);

vertCenteredText(x+width*1/3,y+height/2,'Arrived On-Time');
vertCenteredText(x+width*1/2,y+height/2,'Logged-In On-Time');
vertCenteredText(x+width*2/3,y+height/2,'Tasks Completed On-Time');

function vertCenteredText(x,y,text){
  var ta=ctx.textAlign;
  var tb=ctx.textBaseline;
  ctx.translate(x,y);
  ctx.rotate(-Math.PI/2);
  ctx.textAlign='center';
  ctx.textBaseline='middle';
  ctx.fillText(text,0,0);
  // clean up by undoing our changes to canvas state
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  ctx.textAlign=ta;
  ctx.textBaseline=tb;
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```